# how to make this div resizable

Tags: html, css

i have these two divs:

```
<div class="bubble">
   blablablabla
 <div class="arrow-left"></div>
</div>
```

.

```
.bubble{
    background-color:#156ac6; 
    padding: 15px 10px 10px 10px; 
    color: white;
    font-family:Georgia;
}
.arrow-left {
    position:relative;
    top:42px;
    right:0;
    border-left: 42px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    border-top: 42px solid #156ac6;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jgWmM/

i want this to be flexible, e.g. if i resize the browser, it should also shrink according to width of browser. i dont want media queries. just css. how is it possible?

Comment: I don't see a single table in your code, but chances are you should just use percents.

Comment: "e.g. if i resize the table, "

Comment: Am I missing something? The bubble will adapt to content. If you have spaces in the text it will adjust? It will not, however, go _smaller_ than the longest line. Or have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't set widths on those divs, they should resize according to the browser by default. However, you can set widths in percent to be sure:

```
.bubble { width: 100%; }
.arrow-left { width: 100%; }
```

Also you don't need media queries to do this but media queries are css.

Answer (score 1):

If you set position relative on the bubble. And then position absolute with a bottom of -42px on the arrow and right 0px. The arrow will always be in the bottom right. Then you can use percentages for the width and the bubble will be the size of the container.

HTML

```
        <div class="bubble">
               blablablabla
             <div class="arrow-left"></div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.bubble{
    background-color:#156ac6; 
    padding: 15px 10px 10px 10px; 
    color: white;
    font-family:Georgia;

    position:relative;
    width:60%;
}
.arrow-left {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-42px;
    right:0;
    border-left: 42px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0px solid transparent;
    border-top: 42px solid #156ac6;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ySn36/

Comment: working somehow only in jsfiddle. not in browser :(, why is this?

Comment: In your example you have the bubble inside of a table. A table will generally size to whatever it contains. So if you set a width of the bubble the table will wrap around it causing it not to expand. Try setting the css of your table to be width:100%; Then the bubble will be 60% of the tables width.

Comment: thanks, you are right. now it is working. but bubble is somehow fixed. pls look at this: bibago.de/test.html   if you resize, the position is fixed and doesnot go down. how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

use this it may help

```
.bubble {
    resize: none;
}
.arrow-left {
    resize: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using percents in your heights and/or widths.
You can also use them in the top:

```
top: 10%;
```